# How to find where $1/h(x)$ is concave up and down when you can't easily factor $h(x)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Let $f(x) = 1/(x^2 + x -2)$.  Then $f''(x) = [6 (x^2 + x + 1)] / [(x - 1)^3 (x + 2)^3]$.  The function $f(x)$ is concave down between $-2$ and $1$, but I can't seem to confirm this fact by solving $f''(x) = 0$ and discovering where it is positive and negative.  My first step in solving it is to write $6 (x^2 + x + 1) = 0$, but this has no real solution because this parabola is wholly positive.

I'm seeing for the first time that the idea of solving $f''(x) = 0$ to see where it's crossing the $x$ axis doesn't always work.  It turns out that $f''(x)$ has no roots, but it does take on negative and positive values.

I'm able to pull this one off because I know that $(x^2 + x -2)$ factors as $(x + 2)(x - 1)$, so I know we have discontinuities at $x = -2$ and $x = 1$.  These discontinuities will carry over to $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$, so I can figure out the signs of $f''(x)$ by looking at its values in points in the intervals $x < -2$, $- 2 < x < 1$ and $1 < x$.

So far so good.  What if I could not factor the denominator easily?  For instance, what if $g(x) = 1/(x^4 + 7x + 2)$.  I don't know how to factor this denominator, so I could not apply the strategy above.  How do you treat such a case if you're trying to find where $g(x)$ is concave up and down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While you may not be able to algebraically factor the denominator, you can still achieve sufficient evidence to describe the function's concavity.

From your definition, $h(x) = x^4 + 7x + 2$. We do not need to find a value for the roots, but we just need to tell how many real roots $h(x)$ has to find the number of asymptotes of $\dfrac{1}{h(x)}$, as concavity changes at linear asymptotes. This can be done through Sturm's theorem.

> Note $h(x)$ is not a perfect square, since the $x^2$ term does not exist. This is important for Sturm's theorem to be employed.

---

By [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=The%20theorem,-The%20Sturm%20chain&text=Sturm%27s%20theorem%20states%20that%2C%20if,such%20that%20a%20%3C%20b), we compute the Sturm sequence as follows:

$$h'(x) = 4x^3 + 7 \\ h''(x) = 12x^2 
\\ \quad \\ \text{Let $\%$ denote the euclidean division remainder of 2 polynomials;} \\ g_0(x) = -h(x)\,\%\,h'(x) = -\dfrac{21}{4}x - 2 \\ g_1(x) = -h'(x)\,\%\,h''(x) = -\dfrac{7}{12}
\\ \text{Since, we reached a constant we have completed the sequence.}
\\ \text{Now, we evaluate the signs of $h(x), h'(x), g_0(x), g_1(x)$ at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$}
\\ \text{The difference in their changes should give the number of real roots.}$$

$$ x \to +\infty: \text{sgn}\{h(x), h'(x), g_0(x), g_1(x)\} \to \{+, +, -, -\} \Rightarrow 1 \text{ change} 
\\ x \to -\infty: \text{sgn}\{h(x), h'(x), g_0(x), g_1(x)\} \to \{+, -, +, -\} \Rightarrow 3 \text{ changes} \\ \therefore 3 - 1 = 2 \text{ real roots}$$

---

Let $t_1, t_2$ be these real roots, $t_1 < t_2$. From $h'(x) = 0$, we identify $h(x)$ has **only** $1$ stationary point, at $x = -\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{7}{4}}$. $h''\left(x = -\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{7}{4}}\right) > 0$ communicates this is minimum. Given $h(-\infty) = +\infty$ and $h(+\infty) = +\infty$, and $h\left(x = -\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{7}{4}}\right) = \dfrac{16 - 21\cdot\sqrt[3]{14}}{8} < 0 \implies t_1 < -\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{7}{4}} < t_2$;

Observe $h(x)$ must take the shape of a concave up parabola.

---

We can use the information above to decode the concavity of $\dfrac{1}{h(x)}$, as follows:

$$h(x < t_1) > 0 \implies \lim_{x \to t_1^-}{\dfrac{1}{h(x)}} \to +\infty$$

$$h(t_1 < x < t_2) < 0 \implies \lim_{x \to t_1^+}{\dfrac{1}{h(x)}} \to -\infty$$

$$h(t_1 < x < t_2) < 0 \implies \lim_{x \to t_2^-}{\dfrac{1}{h(x)}} \to -\infty$$

$$h(x > t_2) > 0 \implies \lim_{x \to t_2^+}{\dfrac{1}{h(x)}} \to +\infty$$

$$\dfrac{1}{h\left(x = -\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{7}{4}}\right)} < 0 \text{ is a local maximum }$$

---

$$ \dfrac{1}{h(x)} \neq 0; \lim_{x \to \pm \infty}{\dfrac{1}{h(x)}} \to \dfrac{1}{\infty} \to 0 \implies y = 0 \text{ is an horizontal asymptote} $$

---

We have sufficient evidence to describe that

$$x \in \left(-\infty, t_1\right); h(x) \text{ is increasing} 
\\x \in \left(t_1, -\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{7}{4}}\right); h(x) \text{ is increasing} 
\\x \in \left(-\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{7}{4}}, t_2 \right); h(x) \text{ is decreasing} 
\\x \in \left(t_2, \infty \right); h(x) \text{ is decreasing}$$

$\therefore h\big(x \in \left(-\infty, t_1\right) \cup \left(t_2, \infty\right)\big)$ is concave up.

$\therefore h\big(t_1 < x < t_2 \big)$ is concave down.

> Now finding $t_1, t_2$ is a different story...

Comment: I'm very impressed.  Thank you for bringing Sturm's theorem to my attention. Had never heard of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could always factor as non-integers. All quadratics can be expressed as $(x-r)(x-s)$ for some real $r,s$, which can be found using the quadratic formula. Then you can just generalize:

$$\begin{align}
g(x) &= \frac{1}{(x-r)(x-s)} \\ 
g'(x) &= \frac1{(r-s)(x-s)^2} - \frac1{(r-s)(x-r)^2} \\
g''(x) &= \frac2{(r-s)(x-s)^3} - \frac2{(r-s)(x-r)^3}
\end{align}$$

And so forth. Note that we can do this much more easily, though. Assume $r>s$. Then the graph of $g(x) = 1/(x-r)(x-s)$ has poles at $x=r, x=s$, is concave up in the intervals $[-\infty, s) \cup (r, \infty]$, and is concave down in the interval $(s, r)$. The same is true of its second derivative, fourth derivative, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a neat answer.  When you say --- assume $r > s$ ---, your intention is just to make them different numbers, right?  Otherwise we'd get two concave up parts.  I had never noticed this.  Thank you so much for such an insightful answer.  I wish I could select more than one answer to the question.  Very grateful!

Comment: @user1145880 I think the other answer was more thorough, and deserves the choice/ Mine has only the advantage of being a bit simplified, which is not always the best thing. And yes, I assumed $r>s$ because they need to be different to be interesting (else there are two sections, both concave up), and choosing one to be larger can be done WLOG.